# Could someone please tell me why my wiki tag edit was rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, quality-improvement

I'll be honest here. I don't get many edit rejections. I think I have an accept rate of over 90%. When I edit, I'm trying to contribute and improve things.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6807252

I will admit that this was a minor edit and I prefer making more revisions. However, I in good faith, proposed this edit, certain it would improve things.

I have a college degree, perfect English and am a very good writer. I made the following changes

- Corrected two spelling mistakes. This may seem minor, but I disagree
- Made the references correctly align
- Made a sentence more concise

I got this rejection method

```
This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more
accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm
readability.
```

That seems like a canned response. I don't agree with it.

I would genuinely like to know what was wrong with my edit. As I said, I take pride in my editing skills and making improvements. If there was something wrong, I'd like to know how I can fix this so I can make a better contribution.

Comment: You missed a bullet: - deleted the link to the website.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You removed a link to the project's web site. With that, you removed attribution of an entire paragraph:

> a network application framework which helps users develop high performance and high scalability network applications easily. It provides an abstract event-driven asynchronous API over various transports such as TCP/IP and UDP/IP via Java NIO.

This is taken, verbatim, from the web site you removed. In effect, you've eliminated the attribution we require. If I were reviewing your edit, I'd reject it for this reason.

Your grammatical minor edits were fine. Removal of the link to the project was not.